# How to feather the chroma mask from edges

Tags: opengl, glsl, chromakey

This is the shader i am using to do chroma key , the shader works well but i need to feather the edges of the chroma mask.

How can i do that ?

```
#version 430 core

uniform sampler2D u_tex;     
vec4 keyRGBA = vec4(86.0 / 255.0 , 194.0 / 255.0, 46.0 / 255.0 , 1.0);    // key color as rgba
vec2 keyCC;      // the CC part of YCC color model of key color
uniform vec2 rangeSpill = vec2(0.1, .52);      // the smoothstep range for spill detection
uniform vec2 range = vec2(0.05, 0.21);      // the smoothstep range for chroma detection
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

vec2 RGBToCC(vec4 rgba) {
    float Y = 0.299 * rgba.r + 0.587 * rgba.g + 0.114 * rgba.b;
    return vec2((rgba.b - Y) * 0.565, (rgba.r - Y) * 0.713);
}       

vec2 RGBAToCC (float r, float g, float b) {
    
    float y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;    
    return vec2((b - y) * 0.565, (r - y) * 0.713);
}


vec3 RGBToYCC( vec3 col )
{
    float y = 0.299 * col.r + 0.587 * col.g + 0.114 * col.b;    
    return vec3( y ,(col.b - y) * 0.565, (col.r - y) * 0.713);

}


vec3 YCCToRGB( vec3 col )
{
   float R  = col.x + (col.z - 128) *  1.40200;
   float G  = col.x + (col.y - 128) * -0.34414 + (col.z - 128) * -0.71414;
   float B  = col.x + (col.y - 128) *  1.77200;
   return vec3( R , G , B);

}


vec3 hueShift( vec3 color, float hueAdjust ){ 
     vec3  kRGBToYPrime = vec3 (0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
     vec3  kRGBToI      = vec3 (0.596, -0.275, -0.321);
     vec3  kRGBToQ      = vec3 (0.212, -0.523, 0.311);
     vec3  kYIQToR     = vec3 (1.0, 0.956, 0.621);
     vec3  kYIQToG     = vec3 (1.0, -0.272, -0.647);
     vec3  kYIQToB     = vec3 (1.0, -1.107, 1.704);
     float   YPrime  = dot (color, kRGBToYPrime);
     float   I       = dot (color, kRGBToI);
     float   Q       = dot (color, kRGBToQ);
     float   hue     = atan (Q, I);
     float   chroma  = sqrt (I * I + Q * Q);
     hue += hueAdjust;
     Q = chroma * sin (hue);
     I = chroma * cos (hue);
     vec3    yIQ   = vec3 (YPrime, I, Q);
     return vec3( dot (yIQ, kYIQToR), dot (yIQ, kYIQToG), dot (yIQ, kYIQToB) );
}


float GetYComponent( vec3 color){ 
     vec3  kRGBToYPrime = vec3 (0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
     vec3  kRGBToI      = vec3 (0.596, -0.275, -0.321);
     vec3  kRGBToQ      = vec3 (0.212, -0.523, 0.311);
     vec3  kYIQToR     = vec3 (1.0, 0.956, 0.621);
     vec3  kYIQToG     = vec3 (1.0, -0.272, -0.647);
     vec3  kYIQToB     = vec3 (1.0, -1.107, 1.704);
     float   YPrime  = dot (color, kRGBToYPrime);
     return YPrime;
}

        
void main() {
    vec4 src1Color = texture2D(u_tex,  texCoord);   
    keyCC = RGBAToCC( keyRGBA.r , keyRGBA.g , keyRGBA.b  );
    vec2 CC = RGBToCC(src1Color);   
    float mask = sqrt(pow(keyCC.x - CC.x, 2.0) + pow(keyCC.y - CC.y, 2.0));     
    mask = smoothstep(rangeSpill.x + 0.5, rangeSpill.y, mask);
    if (mask > 0.0 && mask < .8)
    {
      src1Color = vec4( hueShift(src1Color.rgb , 1.8 ) , src1Color.a );  // spill remover           
    }   
    
    // Now the spill is removed do the chroma
     vec2 CC2 = RGBToCC(src1Color);
     float mask2 = sqrt(pow(keyCC.x - CC2.x, 2.0) + pow(keyCC.y - CC2.y, 2.0));
     mask2 = smoothstep(range.x, range.y, mask2);       
    if (mask2 == 0.0) { discard; }
            else if (mask2 == 1.0)
        {   
        FragColor = vec4(src1Color.rgb ,  mask2);
        }
        else 
        {
            vec4 col = max(src1Color - (1.0 - mask2) * keyRGBA, 0.0);               
            FragColor = vec4(hueShift(col.rgb , 0.3 ) , col.a); // do color correction      
        }
        
}
```

This is the base image
[image]

This is the result after chroma keying.
[image]

Also there is not much information avaliable for chroma keying if someone could also give some information about adding more details in the shader.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, you need to extrude the areas where the Chroma key matched. While you could just sample in a pattern (instead of a single point) in a single render pass, that's not quite efficient.

Instead you should rather write the mask to a 1bit (or as much as you would like for transparency) mask texture first. Then you can run a simple 1D shader in X and Y direction over that mask to extrude the already excluded areas by a fixed amount. You need a temporary texture for playing ping-pong either way, and splitting X and Y dimensions requires far less samples in total.

E.g. the minimum opacity in a range of 5px, or a Gaussian blur with a scaler / clamp to keep already full transparent pixels still transparent.

Ultimately, combine your final mask with the source image as usual.